# What is the difference between a factorial analysis for mixed data (FAMD) and a PCA on a dataset where qualitative variable are dummy-encoded?

Tags: categorical-data, pca, covariance-matrix, categorical-encoding, mixed-type-data

There are many variants of the principal component analysis (PCA) framework for discrete variables or a mixture of quantitative and discrete variables.

[image]

*Image from [this book](https://www.datanovia.com/en/product/practical-guide-to-principal-component-methods-in-r).*

However, I am not completely clear about how these methods differ from a PCA on the same data set but with a one-hot / dummy variable encoding of the qualitative variables. I read contradictory statement about it dummy encoding being possible but meaningless.

As far as I can understand from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_analysis_of_mixed_data), the main problem is about extending the notion a variance-covariance matrix in the case of discrete variables. But why is this extension even needed? Doesn't the covariance between a dummy and a quantitative variable make sense? Or between two dummy variables?

I have the intuition that at the end the only difference is about the relative weighting of the dummies in comparison to the quantitative variables, but I struggle showing it formally. And if I am wrong, can one explain why?